# Tensorflow training crashes exceeds 10% of system memory although training with batch size of 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

Training with a batch size of 128/64/32 used to simply empty out the GPU memory after several epochs. 
However, running stochastic batch training actually makes the program stuck at 0% of the 1st epoch.

```
    --------------- Epoch 1 ---------------
  0%|                                                                                          | 0/486 [00:00<?, ?it/s]2019-06-18 18:04:58.581233: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\allocator.cc:108] Allocation of 1207959552 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-06-18 18:04:59.208729: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\allocator.cc:108] Allocation of 1207959552 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-06-18 18:04:59.827425: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\allocator.cc:108] Allocation of 1207959552 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-06-18 18:05:00.497830: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\allocator.cc:108] Allocation of 1207959552 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-06-18 18:05:01.173273: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\allocator.cc:108] Allocation of 1207959552 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```

The GPU used is a GTX 1080, does anyone have any insights? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This warning came during buffer filling in my case. It might be because of the amount of data, number of neurons you are using etc. another reason could be your CPU RAM memory. Check how much memory you have and how much is the program using on execution. If it has low memory, try increasing your CPU RAM memory. For more information, maybe this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18736) might be helpful.